# How do I delete a downloaded iOS software update on iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

In general on newer iOS versions, you can delete downloaded software updates by going to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage > and then finding the update and deleting it from there. [Here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/10/27/how-to-remove-software-update-download-phone-ipad/) is an article outlining the process.

However, it doesn't seem like this is possible on iOS 6. This leads me to my question: how can I delete a downloaded update on iOS 6? The iOS 8.4.1 update was downloaded to my iPhone 5, but I do **not** want to update to that version, accidentally or otherwise. I want to get rid of this update file from my device completely.

Would resetting all contents and settings work? Is there a better way to go about doing this without needing to use such a strong method of resetting everything?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to back up the iPhone via iCloud Backup. Then sign out of the iPhone, and then "Erase all Content and Settings".

Once the iPhone comes back on, setup the iPhone properly, then when you get to the "Apps & Data" screen, choose restore from iCloud backup, and choose the recent backup.

Comment: Supposedly this can be done on-device: "Settings>General>Reset>Erase All Contents and Settings - should delete the OTA updates." [Source](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37407)